# Liferay Search Container

Tags: liferay

I have used Liferay search container for displying data for custom entity and it is working.
I have another portlet where data coming from REST API so is there any way that I can use search container? OR I need to use datatable for that.
My REST API is with pagination and without pagination.

Comment: Ok for datatable, search-container is not made to have datasource from rest api...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SearchContainer` with any data. Its uses with DB is more natural of course but where the data comes from is irrelevant as long as SearchContainer can access it. So you can build your own service that talks to remote API and provides data to the `SearchContainer`. In case you haven't done that for your other service, see [here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/export-import/export-import-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/exportimport/web/internal/display/context/ExportTemplatesToolbarDisplayContext.java#L118-L160) for example how it can be build server side.